# Android Studio emulating very slow network speed

Tags: android

I set the network speed of AVD to GSM but it takes very short amount of time to download a 600k file.  I'd like to lower the emulated network speed in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official [emulator tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#netspeed):

To set the network speed at emulator startup, use the `-netspeed` emulator option with a supported  value, as listed in the table below. Here are some examples:

```
emulator -netspeed gsm
emulator -netspeed 0.1 0.1
```

To make changes to network speed while the emulator is running, connect to the console and use the netspeed command with a supported  value.

```
network speed 0.1 0.1
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#starting). You need to pass the parameters above when starting the emulator.

Comment: If you want to connect to the emulator console, execute `telnet localhost <console-port>`. [Link](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/developing/tools/android_emulator_console.html)

Comment: Thank you.  I use the command `network speed 0.1 0.1` to slow down the emulated network speed.