# How to simulate slow localhost speed for Android app testing

Tags: android, api, localhost

I'm developing an Android app which has multiple downloading tasks. And I'm using localhost for testing APIs. But the localhost's speed is too fast so I can't test my app's performance on realtime speed base.

I've seen how to slowdown speed on Chrome but as I'm testing my Android app so it's not working for me.

So how can I simulate slow localhost speed for testing my Android app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio emulating very slow network speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701516/android-studio-emulating-very-slow-network-speed)

Comment: No I'm not testing it on emulator. I'm testing it on my own phone.

Comment: Limit the speed on wireless router configuration?

Comment: Limiting speed in wireless router will slow down internet speed for every person using it. I just want to slow down my own Linux laptop's lampp server speed. So i can test it without interrupting actual internet speed.

Comment: I think, if it is possible, go to router configuration page, and limit your Android device's speed only.

Comment: Thats not the correct solution because while surfing internet for another stuff it loads slow. I just want to slow down "localhost" speed.

Comment: I once used Charles Proxy for that:
https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/throttling/